# File Upload Return

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new to .NET Core MVC and trying to make an application that uploads a file, I've managed to do that but when it uploads the file it takes you to the file count and size whereas I just want it to remain on the same page does anybody know how I can do this?

```
  [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        var webroot = _env.WebRootPath;
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);
        var filePaths = new List<string>();
        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if(formFile.Length > 0)
            {                   
                var filePath = Path.Combine(/*AppContext.BaseDirectory*/webroot, $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}.txt"); /*Path.GetTempPath()+ Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".txt";*/
                filePaths.Add(filePath);
                TempData["filepath"] = filePath;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);                        

                }
            }
        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePaths });
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: [Dropzone](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) is a nice dragdrop file upload library, here is a [tutorial](http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/31-File_Upload) and a [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/LazZiya/FileUpload)

Comment: How are you calling this action to upload the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can do using the ajax calling for this, submit the form using the Ajax call

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: yeah but the ajax code you can write it right for the form upload.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to add as comment...
We can use partial view concept, people use this concept to avoid this situation. Else we can also use IFrame.

I'll prefer to go with partial view concept ease to handle multiple event and scenario.

Happy coding